# Is it possible to extract cell reference from a hyperlink?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been researching this one for a while now with no luck, so thought I would open it up here...

Let's say you have two worksheets in an excel workbook, e.g. sheet1 and sheet2.

Now, in sheet2 cell A1, say you have a hyperlink that refers/points/links to sheet1 cell A1. In other words, the value of the cell reference of the hyperlink at sheet2!A1 is sheet1!A1

Do you know if there is a formula or function that would return the cell reference of that hyperlink.

i.e.

```
=<formula-or-function>(sheet2!A1)
```

which returns 'sheet1!A1' as its result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the .SubAddress from the [Hyperlinks.Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838786.aspx).

```
'by the active cell
With ActiveCell
    Debug.Print .Hyperlinks.Item(1).SubAddress
End With

'by worksheet and cell address
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D6")
    Debug.Print .Hyperlinks.Item(1).SubAddress
End With
```

This is, of course, VBA. I know of no way to perform this action with a worksheet formula short of a User Defined Function (aka UDF) written in VBA.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped, much appreciated.